# How Did the GNU libstdc++ Library Find Its Way into Our App?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, clang, libstdc++

#### The Question

This is **not** about legal advice. We are asking **why/how the GNU libstdc++ library seemingly found its way into our app**, when to the best of our knowledge it should not be part of our app, according to our IDE setup.

#### Context

We recently used Android's documentation to [include open source notices](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/opensource) in our app. After using this, an activity can be shown presumably listing all the open-source software (OSS) dependencies in our app. Clicking on any of these dependencies shows the relevant OSS license.

In the list of autogenerated OSS dependencies there is an entry titled `STL`, which when clicked displays the following text:

> SGI STL
>
> The STL portion of GNU libstdc++ that is used with gcc3 and gcc4 is licensed under the GPL, with the following exception:
>
> [...]

The problem is that to the best of our knowledge we do not use the GNU libstdc++ nor do we use the gcc3/gcc4 compiler in our app, according to our IDE setup.

#### IDE Setup

We use Android Studio and the JNI to also compile code written in C++. Our C++ code uses the standard library (e.g. we use the `string` class among others).

[This guide](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support) from Android's documentation states that

> LLVM's libc++ is the C++ standard library that has been used by the Android OS since Lollipop, and as of NDK r18 is the only STL available in the NDK.

We are way past Lollipop and the NDK we use is 21.4.7075529, so this should be enough to guarantee that the standard library used in our app is LLVM's libc++ (and ***not*** GNU's libstdc++). But in any case, we also specify Clang (which is part of the LLVM) as the compiler, just to be sure.

All of this is reflected in our build.gradle (app) file, some parts of which are pasted below:

```
...
android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    ndkVersion "21.4.7075529"
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                ...
                arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared","-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just in case it is relevant, we also include the following line in our CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
```

So what are we doing wrong here? There should not be any reference to GNU libstdc++, nor to the gcc compiler. Can anyone please help? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you *know* that libstdc++ is "in your app"? How did you check that?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude We did not know until we followed Android's documentation to include open source notices (please have a look in the question's "Context" section). To be honest, we still don't *know* that libstdc++ is in our app, because e.g. the autogenerated list of dependencies might somehow be wrong...

Comment: Likely `libstdc++` is a transitive dependency of one or more of the 3rd party libraries you're using. Is there a problem in having the dependency, does it affect you in any way other than appearing on the list of OSS dependencies? If yes, then you'll need to find out which libraries end up depending on `libstdc++`, and replace those with ones that don't have the dependency.

Comment: The linked page also says that licenses of dependencies including Google Play's dependencies are included. Also, that notice looks very out-dated. It refers to GCC3 and GCC4 and doesn't specify the GPL version. I doubt it refers to current libstdc++, but rather some files taken from an old version. A google search finds the same wording with references to Google Play services, e.g. `play-services-auth-17.0.0.aar\third_party_licenses.txt` and GVR Android SDK.

Comment: @Cristik Thanks for the comment -- the only reason we are trying to avoid the libstrc++ dependency are potential licensing implications. I know SO is not the place to discuss licensing issues, but our preference is for anything mentioning the GPL to not be part of our app. Despite the fact that the libstdc++ dependency's text comes with an exception (which I did not paste in the question), things are still somehow unclear to us on this front.

Comment: @user17732522 Indeed, it looks outdated (eg dated back to when there was only GPL 1.0?). If anyone is interested, [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/license.html#manual.intro.status.license.gpl) is the current version of the license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it for example in the `com.google.android.gms:play-services-oss-licenses` dependency itself.

I did it by running the `<variant>OssLicensesTask` multiple times, and using divide and conquer to comment out half of the dependencies that can potentially include that license and check the generated `third_party_license_metadata` file to see if it contains `STL`.

And then, if you look at [the `.aar` file](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#com.google.android.gms:play-services-oss-licenses:17.0.0) you can verify this. After you unpack it, there are `third_party_licenses` files:

[image: aar contents]

And there is `"STL": {"length": 680, "start": 3372}` in the `third_party_licenses.json` that points to this part of `third_party_licenses.txt`:

```
STL:

SGI STL

The STL portion of GNU libstdc++ that is used with gcc3 and gcc4 is licensed
under the GPL, with the following exception:

# As a special exception, you may use this file as part of a free software
# library without restriction.  Specifically, if other files instantiate
# templates or use macros or inline functions from this file, or you compile
# this file and link it with other files to produce an executable, this
# file does not by itself cause the resulting executable to be covered by
# the GNU General Public License.  This exception does not however
# invalidate any other reasons why the executable file might be covered by
# the GNU General Public License.
```

I checked that if I leave all dependencies except for the `com.google.android.gms:play-services-oss-licenses` then `STL` is not listed, so in my case that was the only one, but it may be different for you.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, @arekolek! You are right, this is the exact license text that we get as well. As @Cristik commented, it comes from a transient dependency. We use the same `com.google.android.gms:play-services-oss-licenses` dependency, so we surely get the `STL` text from there (if not also from another transient dependency). Could you explain how you could list the dependencies and get the screenshot you show in your answer? Is that done in Android Studio?

Comment: Regarding dependencies, I just commented out dependencies in my `build.gradle` and re-ran the plugin to generate licenses. As for the screenshot, I downloaded the `.aar` from the link above, changed the extension from `.aar` to `.zip` and unpacked it.